# Unity tilemap bug

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a tilemap that uses a composite collider. My character moves on the tilemap perfectly.However, the enemy(a ghost that flies toward the player nonstop) can push the player inside the tilemap(push through the collider).

I have tried to both move enemy with transform and rigid body, and non of that worked. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

is your rigid body set to continuous? if not the rigid body can sometimes be pushed into colliders between frames.

Comment: i figure out the solution is set rigid body to dynamic then handle the movement with different code.